# Is it possible to define custom sound style (or instrument)?

Tags: style, sound

For example, you can specify the style or instrument as "Violin" in a `SoundNote` like:

```
SoundNote[0, 1, "Violin"]
```

Here mathemetica gives a list of pre-defined styles. Is it possible to create your own custom style, so to stick it inside the available styles like the built-in ones?